# Magneto and the loss of his powers

Tags: story-identification, marvel, x-men, episode-identification, magneto

Repeatedly it is said that Magneto lost half of his powers while trying to destroy some Apocalypse starship. Do you know the name of the comic, or is it just a fact mentioned - but never depicted - in the story?

Comment: "*Repeatedly it is said that Magneto lost half of his powers...*" - for the sake of a complete question (especially for those, like me, that haven't seen this mentioned previously) would you be able to cite some occurrences of this being said, and by whom?

Comment: Sure. In the 90's Fox cartoon and through all the Age of Apocalipse series. There's also several mentions in other Xmen adventures, perhaps in Onslaught's saga, but this I am not so sure.

Comment: I think in a more canonical timeline, Magneto is considered to lost his powers again Prof. X, and that's why Xavier is in a wheelchair. But here I just want to ask about Age of Apocalipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This happened in *X-Men Chronicles 1: "Origins"* (1995)

[As Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_(comics)#cite_note-13):

> In the Age of Apocalypse, Ship was nearly destroyed by Magneto when it
>   endangered the lives of his X-Men. This was after they successfully
>   thwarted the plans of En Sabah Nur's Horsemen to take control of the
>   United States nuclear arsenal. The battle between Ship and Magneto
>   left the X-Men leader drained and unable to ever fully restore his
>   magnetic powers.

From the referenced comic:

[image]

Magneto overloads his powers in an attempt to stop Gideon and avert the launch of nuclear missiles.

Later, while still weakened from his previous exertion, Magneto damages Apocalypse's ship.

[image]

The Wikipedia description seems a bit confusing, since Magneto didn't entirely destroy the ship, and calling it a "battle between Ship and Magneto" seems a bit inaccurate, but it does occur after the Horsemen try to take control of the nuclear arsenal, so....

Comment: I always thought that he lost his powers when travelling to the moon (and facing there Death). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user2820579 - If you tell me which comic that's in, I could see if that's the case.